# How to decode bitmap with sample size not equals power of 2?

Tags: android

Simple example:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inSampleSize = scale;
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, opts);
```

When I'm passing `scale` value not equal to power of two, bitmap is still scaled by closest power of 2 value. For example, if `scale = 3` then actual scale become `2` for some reason. Maybe it's because I'm using hardware acceleration?

Anyway, how can I scale bitmap by non power-of-2 value without allocation memory for full bitmap?

P.S. I know, that using power of two is much faster, but in my case time isn't such critical and I need image scaled **exactly** by provided scale (otherway it's become too big or too small) - I'm woking with image processing, so big image itself not such a problem (`ImageView` scales it to required size), but it takes extra time to apply some filter for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the documentation for [`inSampleSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize):

> Note: the decoder will try to fulfill this request, but the resulting bitmap may have different dimensions that precisely what has been requested. Also, powers of 2 are often faster/easier for the decoder to honor.

You are not guaranteed exact dimensions. Since memory sounds like it is a concern, I would use your current method to get the image to larger than what you need but something that fits better with your memory requirements than the source image. Then use a different method like [`Bitmap.createScaledBitmap`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29) to get it to your exact dimensions.